# How can we conclude that such function $f(x)$ either exists or not ?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In this PDF file [here](http://mathlets.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/Isoclines1.pdf) ( file from OCW.MIT ) , problem 1 : part c .

For the  differential equation , $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - x^2 $ ,
There exists a number $y_o$ such that  if $y$ is a solution with $y(0) > y_0 $
then $y$ becomes large as $x$ becomes large, while if $y(0) < y_0$ then $y$ decreases as $x$
increases where  $0.66 < y_o < 0.68$ .

Is there some function $f(x)$ such that $y(x) > f(x)$ for all $x > 0$ whenever $y$ is a
solution with $0 < y(0) < y_0$ ?

when I used a software ( Works on the browser ) which is provided by the site , ( [here](http://mathlets.org/daimp/Isoclines.html) ) and I have chosen the required DF , I  guessed from the Geometrical sketch that  such $f$ exists , namely , any function $f$ such that $f(0)<y(o)$ satisfy the condition , bur the exercise asks for explanation , So any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem right. If $y_0\ne 0$ then $dy/dx$ starts with a positive value and hence $y$ is increasing. So if you start with say $y_0=0.6$ then at start you have $dy/dx=0.6^2-x^2$ which stays positive for a short while hence $y$ will increase on that interval.

Or am I missing something obvious?

I misunderstood the problem. You are talking about the asymptotics of the solution, while I thought you  are referring to the solution on the entire $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your answer more!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want an explicit formula for $f$, or else you can let $f(x) = \inf_{0<y(0)<y_0} y(x;y(0))$. (Here, $y(x;y(0))$ is the solution to the ODE with initial condition $y(0)$ - i.e., $y(0;y(0))=y(0)$.)

**Hint.** Since you want a *lower* bound on $y$ which is *uniform* for *all* solutions (in the given family), try to bound your vector field below by a bound not depending on these solutions. That is, for your ODE $y'=g(x,y)$, find G(x) such that $g(x,y) \ge G(x)$ for all $y$. Do you see how to proceed then?